# Using Excel formula to find employee working times

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an Excel sheet with over 1,500 rows of data.  Each row tracks an employees start and stop time for a specific task and order number. I want to add up the total time for each person and/or location.

I tried VLOOKUP to try and do this, but it just returns an error. For example, if I want to look for Karen's total work time, I would do something like VLOOKUP(Karen,F:F,9,TRUE).  What I get in return is an #REF!.  I suspect this has to do with there being something like 100 rows that are related to Karen's work and the VLOOKUP isn't going to add all the values found together.

What I want is for the output, in one cell, to show the total time. I figured I might have to do something were it finds all of Karen's times and dumps them into a new column, and from there, I can sum them all up into a single cell to get the total time.

[Example of Excel document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erhoN.png)

Comment: Perhaps use SUMIF or SUMIFS but that could be confirmed with some sample data. EDIT: Based on your sample data, use SUMIF.

Comment: This works! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like BigBen said in his comment, you should use **SUMIFS** to achieve that, along with a new column like you figured out.

I made a simple sheet in Google Sheets to exemplify it (functions used are the same in Excel).

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v5ft9y5nleGMzkd1vS8eiuS0CRnLbPaxLhbR39r1vVU/edit?usp=sharing) the link to it, and below is an image of it's contents:

[image]